# Postgres - Find only by UUID

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've got PostgreSQL DB with multiple schemas and tables in that schemas. Every row in table have PRIMARY UUID like `"Ref_Key" => "41bf3b1e-91f0-491c-a6bd-c48a17e7c252"`

Is it possible to find row only by it UUID, without specifying schema and table?

Comment: If you really don't even know which table you should be querying, then it might indicate a database design flaw.

Comment: No-no, in fact purpose of this: my users can create tasks that linked to literally every defined object (Table) in base - Cars, Customers, etc. Of course I can provide way to link objects by creating link table with "schema, table, key" but it's interesting for me is it possible by knowing only UUID.

Comment: With a relational database like PostgreSQL, you must identify the schema, table, and key to retrieve a row.  Maybe some type of NoSQL database can identify what information you want with just a key.

Comment: This indeed sounds like a really strange database design. But what you could do, is either create a view that unions all `ref_key` columns and the table where they come from. Or write a function that uses dynamic SQL to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You can only query tables that explicitly appear in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement.